# Rx: Run code after all subscriptions have completed for one 'next'

Tags: ecmascript-6, rxjs, reactive-extensions-js

Say I have a subject somewhere in my code

```
mySubject$ = new Subject()
```

Elsewhere in the code, any number of subscriptions are made, e.g.

```
someSubscription = mySubject$.subscribe(() => console.log('I love streams'))
anotherSubscription =  mySubject$.subscribe(() => console.log('me too!'))
```

When I `.next()`the subject, both subscription fire as expected.

How can I hook into the rx mechanism so that I can run some code after all subscriptions have finished running their code (for that single `next` event)?

Is there something like `mySubject$.onAllSubscriptionsCompleted(() => console.log('all done')`

Or what are alternatives to achieving this?

Comment: Why you need to execute something like this, could you describe the underlying problem you are trying to solve? (Because looks like the problem in not with ReactiveX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RxJS doesn't have such backward *(upward?)* event propagation, unless its a subscription/unsubscription.

Strictly saying: **its not an Rx-way to have that relation between subscriber and an observable**.

Yet, there are ways to achieve that:

- you could have another Subject(s) to push "handled" notifications to, and handle from your observable. A nightmarish thing to support, imho
- have your subscribers to **resubscribe** and react in your observable to that. A speculation on that subscription/unsubscription event propagation. Seems even more nightmarish. And it should
- have some kind of back pressure, simplest of which is a `concatMap`, inside of which you could perform all your handling. Yet with this approach you'll have to rethink those generator-handlers relations

Heres a rough illustration of a flow using [`concatMap`](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/concatMap/)

```
                                handler1
source$ -> concatMap( forkJoin( handler2 ) ) -> subscribe( here all handlers finished )
                                handler3
```

If you want to learn more on back pressure, heres an article on [backpressure techniques in RxJS](https://medium.com/@kddsky/pauseable-observables-in-rxjs-58ce2b8c7dfd)